# Visual Studio Intellisense Autocomplete for Blazor Components

Tags: visual-studio, blazor

When I use a component, built in or otherwise, is there a way to show the available parameters? For example, `<EditForm>` has a Model parameter and if I know this, I can manually type it in and it changes color to confirm I have it right. The more obscure parameters like EditContext are hard to find even in the documentation. Is there a discovery method?  Ctrl + Shift + Space does not work.

Comment: ctrl+space works for me. Even just typing a space in the markup tag pops up the available options.

Comment: Make sure you have enabled Options->Preview Features->Enable experimental Razor Editor in Visual Studio and the experience with autocomplete becomes better.

Comment: You may want to download and install VS2019 Preview Edition.  They are working on enhancements to the editor for .razor pages.  Not sure if it will address your specific question, but from what I can tell it looks like an improvement compared to the standard editor in VS2019.